# how to check if the value of column is inside a provided valid list from another query

Tags: sql, hive

I have two queries the first one give me the following information:

```
SELECT
     x.id_receipt,
     x.id_employee,
     x.product_id,
     x.receipt_date,
     bb.product_name,
from receipt x 
Left join product bb on x.id_product=bb.id
```

The next one is :

```
 SELECT

     a.id,
     v.allowed_product

from employee a 
Left join valid_product v on a.id=v.id_employee
```

For each employee , there is a list of valid product.
How can I check in the first query if each shopping was an allowed shopping for the employee?

I want to check if the bb.product_name is inside the list of allowed product for each employee from the second query

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just do this with an additional `join`:

```
select x.id_receipt, x.id_employee, x.product_id, x.receipt_date,
       bb.product_name,
from receipt x join
     product bb
     on x.id_product = bb.id join
     valid_product vp
     on vp.id_employee = x.id_employee and vp.allowed_product = bb.id;
```

Because the products have to match, there is no need for a `left join`.

Comment: I think every time( per each id_reciept), I should check it with a list from second query

Comment: For the record, a WHERE EXISTS clause is logically equivalent but might be safer with older versions of Hive (implies that the smaller _valid_product_ table is stored in memory, in a hash map, on all query nodes -- otherwise Hive might mistakely try to load the larger table in memory, and that would not end well)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the `WHERE` clause to specify what you are looking for. Like:

```
SELECT bb.product_name
FROM receipt as x, employee as a
WHERE x.bb.product_name = a.allowed_product
```

Comment: I think every time( per each id_reciept), I should check it with a list from second query

Comment: @Alma > Why? Because that's the naive way you would implement it in Java or C# ? The list is the same for all receipts, after all. In logical terms, the order of queries makes no difference. You need to _think_ in SQL and reason about relationships; let the query optimizer handle the execution logic.